# Rails 4 force default route parameter to be included in generated URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm wrestling with routing and default values for optional parameters. Given the route:

```
    get '/product/:key(/:env(/:version))', to: 'delivery#widget_view',
    defaults: { env: 'live' }, as: :product_view
```

I understand if I give it a **version**, then I should have to give it an **env** as well. When I

```
link_to 'view it', key: 'mykey', env: 'live', version: 6
```

The resulting URL is

```
/product/mykey/6
```

And then that ends up creating **params[env] = 6**, and no value for **version**

If I remove the defaults or make :env required by removing (), 'live' is explicitly included in the generated URL. This my solution for now, but is there someway to have Rails give me :env when I supply :version?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Make `env` param required as follows

```
get '/product/:key/:env(/:version)', to: 'delivery#widget_view',
  defaults: { env: 'live' }, as: :product_view
```

When you call `product_view_path` without passing `env`, the default value will be used

```
product_view_path('mykey') => '/product/mykey/live'
```

Your question is: Is there someway to have Rails give me :env when I supply :version?. Yes, you can call `product_view_path` and pass `version` without passing `env`

```
product_view_path('mykey', version: 6) => '/product/mykey/live/6'
```

Comment: I think you've misread the issue I've outlined. When the env parameter is set to optional in the route (default = live) and I provide the default value (env=live) to `link_to` the env value is not included in the generated link.

Comment: @mr_than I assume what you want to achieve is: set a default value for :env, if you don't specify a value for :env, the default value should be used. Making :env optional or mandatory is not what matters. Makes sense?